# Vagrant, Mercurial Keyring: constantly requests password for encrypted keyring

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-keyring, python-keyring

So I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox via Vagrant, and want to set up Mercurial so that it doesn't constantly ask for a password when pulling latest. In that regard, I've installed Mercurial-Keyring, and changed my ~/.hgrc file to look like:

```
[extensions]
mercurial_keyring =

[auth]
ono.schemes = https
ono.prefix = <URL>
ono.username = <username>
```

However, now it asks me to enter a password for the encrypted keyring every time I want to use Mercurial - even on the same session.

Does anyone know what the cause of this is?